# Meaning of colored ring around iris

Tags: eye, diagnostics, iris

There seem to be various conditions that affect the color of the outer edge of the iris, such as:

- [Fleischer ring - Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fleischer_ring)
- [Arcus senilis](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arcus_senilis)
- [Kayser–Fleischer ring](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kayser%E2%80%93Fleischer_ring)
- [Limbal ring](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Limbal_ring)

and I imagine there are others.

Generally they can indicate an underlying medical condition (e.g. the Fleisher ring is indicative of
[Keratoconus](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Keratoconus)).

The limbal ring is said to indicate good health, but I couldn't find any hard citation for this:

[image: https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/e/e8/Blue_eye_2.jpg/800px-Blue_eye_2.jpg]

What is a list of all such rings, and methods for distinguishing between them?